# Laravel relationships category and posts

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Occurred a problem for adding relationships categories and posts. In the database there is three tables:

1. categories(category_id, title)
2. posts(post_id, text,title)
3. category_post(category_id, post_id).

Need to adding table category_post, but not adding. This is model category and post as well as their relationships.

```
    class Category extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
class Post extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'post';
    protected $primaryKey = 'post_id';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }

    //Method add post. Called in the controller
    public static function add($data)
    {
        try {
            $post = new Post;
            $post->title = $data['title'];
            $post->text = $data['text'];

            $category = Category::find(1);
            $category->posts()->save($post);
        }catch (Exception $e){
            return $e;
        }

        return $category;
    }
}
```

Returns an Exception.

Comment: What exception? What's the error message? If you don't see it in your browser enable debugging in `config/app.php` or take a look at the log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: It's `belongsToMany` relationship that you need. Or get rid of the pivot table and add `category_id` to the `posts` table if it's a 1-m relation.

Comment: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'category_id' in 'field list'' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\laravel.local\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:369 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\laravel.local\www\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(369):